# How to check if a document has been already added in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection of urls.

**When adding new urls I want to check if they had been already added, if it's not the case then add it.** (the urls are unique)

```
 $db->url->find(array('url' => $linkurlcache));
 $db->url->insert(array('url' => $linkurlcache));
```

This is what I've tried (extremely bad)

```
$var = $db->url->find(array('url' => $linkurlcache))->limit(1);
foreach($var as $var1){if($var1['url'] == $linkurlcache){$j = 0;}else{$j = 1;}}
        if($j == 0){
            $db->url->insert(array('url' => $linkurlcache));
        }else{
                echo "exists";
        }
```

---

I'm migrating from MySQL(used a MySqlDb class):

```
$Db->where('url', $linkurlcache);
if($results = $Db->get('tbl_url')){echo "exists";}else{

        $insertData = array('url' => $linkurlcache);
        if ($Db->insert('tbl_url', $insertData)){echo "added";} 
        echo $linkurlcache;

};
```

---

I've looked everywhere on their docs (on MongoDB.org and PHP.net) also on stackoverflow but I can't find a solution.

So could you help me with a solution, or a smart workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to JohnnyHK's suggestion on using `findOne()` to check if the document exists, you have a few other options depending on your document structure:

1) If your `urls` are stored one per document, use an [`upsert`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%7B%7Bupserts%7D%7D), which will insert if the url doesn't exist or update the existing document if it does.

2) If your `urls` are stored in an array within a document, use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) which will only append if the value doesn't exist already in the array.

Comment: I've tried: `$db->url->update(array("url" => $linkurlcache),array('$inc' => array("url" => $linkurlcache)),array("upsert" => true));`

Comment: You don't want to increment (`$inc`) the url, you want to `$set` it.  So something like: `$db->url->update(array("url" => $linkurlcache),array('$set' => array("url" => $linkurlcache)),array("upsert" => true));`

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to use [`findOne`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php) instead:

```
$var = $db->url->findOne(array('url' => $linkurlcache));
if ($var == NULL) {
    $db->url->insert(array('url' => $linkurlcache));
}else{
    echo "exists";
}
```